# magento: how to show custom attributes from general tab in front page automatically

Tags: magento

when we upload one product, there is a default attribute set "Default", and in the general tab, there are many default attributes like below image:
[image]

well,  i added one more custom attribute named "size",  when i drag 'size' to general tab on the left, that mean the product has one more attribute.  if i want to show the size attribute in the product view page of front end page, i have to put the code: "$_product->getAttributeText('size')"， if i added lots of custom attributes, i have to put lots of codes manually.  so, my question is how i can show all custom attributes automatically instead of adding one by one manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is allready done by magento.
Mark your attributes as vissible in frontend and thats it.

Have a look at the template attributes.phtml in path app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view

```
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<!--h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2-->
<div class="data-table accordion" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if  (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode()))  &&  ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) {  ?>
    <div class="clearer <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?>">
        <div class="trigger"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></div>
        <div class="triggerContent" style="display: none;"><span><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></span></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

```
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
```

Comment: i can find out attributes.phtml,  but i do not know how to make it vissible, because i change the layout of catalog/product/view.phtml, maybe i removed some coding,  could you know which code is related with attributes.phtml in /catalog/product/view.phtml ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the default file from /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view to your theme directory

/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view